# Center an equation

Tags: equations, align

```
 \documentclass[12pt, a4paper,fleqn]{report}

\doublespacing
\usepackage[comma,super,sort&compress]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{rsc.bst} 
\usepackage{comment}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }


\begin{document}
\section{Molecular dynamics simulations} 

....content....

\begin{equation}
\centering
m_\mathit{i} \frac{\delta^2\mathbf{r_\mathit{i}}}{\delta \mathit{t}^2}= \mathbf{F_\mathit{i}},\mathit{i} = 1....N.
\end{equation}
```

Comment: remove `\centering` in equation. It is centered without it.

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't work.

Comment: What's your documentclass (with options)?

Comment: What class file you are using?

Comment: \documentclass[12pt, a4paper,fleqn]{report}

Comment: Remove `fleqn` and it works.

Comment: `fleqn` stands for "flush left equations" Just for your information.

Answer (score 3):

The `fleqn` class option causes equations to be left-aligned (you specifically ask for this feature). Removing it restores the default behavior: centered alignment.

Comment: Removing the `fleqn` option must be a dupe.